# How to Cut Dried Beef Tendon?

Tags: dogs, treats

I have a dog who loves to eat dried beef tendons (called [dental tendons](https://www.naturesowndogchews.com/product/small-dog-dental-tendons/)), but she also has a tendency to vomit soon after finishing one. I suspect this is because they are somewhat too big for her and I would like to try giving her half a tendon to see if that is easier to keep down, but I can't actually cut one in half - I have tried cutting through one with some shears and sawing through it with a steak knife, but I haven't been able to make any real progress.
Is there any way to cut these into smaller pieces? I feel like I'm missing something obvious with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I always use poulty shears to cut tough dog treats into smaller pieces. They're meant to cut a raw chicken or other bird - including bones - into manageable pieces. I've never had any dog treats actually withstand the shears, but tendons might fray into individual fibres and not cut very well.